# R change list of vectors to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a `list` of different sized vectors that look like this:

```
> test
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

What would be the best way to transform this into a `data.frame` with each `list` element as a column, while filling in missing rows with NA like so?

```
> test2
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  1
2 NA  2  2
3 NA  3  3
4 NA  4  4
5 NA NA  5
6 NA NA  6
7 NA NA  7
```

When I run `do.call(cbind.fill,test)`, I get this:

```
  V1 V1 V1
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
3  1  3  3
4  1  4  4
5  1  1  5
6  1  2  6
7  1  3  7
```

Trying suggestion:

```
> do.call(rbind.data.frame, test)
  c.1L..1L..1L. c.1L..2L..2L. c.1L..3L..3L. c.1L..1L..4L. c.1L..2L..5L. c.1L..3L..6L. c.1L..1L..7L.
1             1             1             1             1             1             1             1
2             1             2             3             1             2             3             1
3             1             2             3             4             5             6             7
```

Comment: Do a Google search for `cbind.fill`.

Comment: @joran Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying `do.call(cbind.fill,test)` however I'm unsure of how to pass on the argument `fill=NA` to a do call function

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: please see above, I've included the problem

Comment: Have you tried: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, test)`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I've put the output above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
test<-list(c(1),c(1:4),c(1:7))
library(qpcR)
do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na,test)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base **R** solution would be:

```
test <- list(1,1:4,1:7)

do.call(cbind,lapply(test, `[`, 1:7))
```

or dynamically:

```
m <- max(sapply(test, length))
do.call(cbind,lapply(test, `[`, 1:m))
```